# Fusion charts free on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, graph, fusioncharts

Hi i am using Fusion charts free with Rail 2.3.5

I tried to simulate the single_array example provided in the documentation but instead of graph it is showing me the following message

The method used is setDataXML.The XML is

```
#Creates xml with values for sales data of products #along with their names.
#The values required for building the xml is obtained as parameter arr_data 
#It expects an array in which each element is 
#itself an array with first element as label and second element as value 
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new xml.graph(:caption=>'Sales by Product', :numberPrefix=>'$', :formatNumberScale=>'0',:decimalPrecision=>'0') do 
  for item in arr_data xml.set(:name=>item[0], :value=>item[1],:color=>''+get_FC_color) 
  end 
end
```

Anybody seen this message before >? i am using Firefox with flash player > 9

Answer (score 0):

"The method used is setDataXML.The XML is" is a log message from FusionCharts RoR.
After this, it should print the xml.
Looks like your xml is incorrect. Please remove the comments from the builder file and see if it works.

Please see a sample application posted at [FusionCharts in RoR 2.3.5](http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic27405-34-1.aspx)